# Adding a Value outside of the Auto Complete - jQuery Plugin: Tokenizing Autocomplete Text Entry

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I'm using the following JQUERY Autocomplete plug-in:
[jQuery Plugin: Tokenizing Autocomplete Text Entry](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/)

What'd I'm unable to figure out is how to add a value to the list from outside of the autocomplete dropdown list.

The reason I want to do this is the autocomplete searches for locations, if a location is not found, there is an "ADD" modal dialog where users can add a location. After they add/submit the location I would like that new value to be automatically added to the autocomplete input.

Here is the JS I'm trying to get to submit the new value to the autocomplete input:

```
$.TokenList.submitLocation.add_token_values("99", "Alpha");
```

Here's the JS that initiates the Autocomplete input:

```
$(function(){               
$("#locationlist").tokenInput("/locations/autosuggest/", {
hintText: "Type the location name",
noResultsText: "No results",
searchingText: "Searching...",
callback: submit locationList
})
});
```

** I've found in jquery.tokeninput.js, the function add_token (item), but haven't been able to call it successfully.

Ideas?

Comment: check out the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539660/jquery-tokeninput-add-if-not-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://github.com/chadisfaction/jQuery-Tokenizing-Autocomplete-Plugin.  It is a slightly modified version of the one you pointed to on loopj.com  The only thing it doesn't seem to do well (and I plan on fixing it at some point and submitting a patch to the author) is taking tags that already existed and putting them in the box already.