# Populate JQuery TokenInput on AJAX event

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

Let say a jQuery TokenInput is attached with a text field with a pre populate parameter defined during its initialization.

Now I want to populate that input field with some tokens on an event trigger without re-initialization of this plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution of my work. Thats why I am posting here so that others can benefit from this answer.

Let say Occupation is my field with id "occupation".

```
$("#occupation").tokenInput("add", {id: 1, name: "Software Engineer"});
```

"add" is a function which adds the json record as a token on the fly.

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: @JohnMax, "add" is the built-in function provided by tokeninput. You just need to apply tokenInput on text field and if you want to populate a field with some token then provide json in the second parameter. For example, In my case I am prepopulating only one tag. Vote Up :)